# How to run program from command line?

Tags: java, command-line

I am trying to write random numbers to a file. SO basically one number on each line and the method name takes the filepath argument and long n argument which is the number of random numbers generated.
This is what I have so far:

```
public  void generate(long n, String filePath) throws FileNotFoundException  
    {
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("filePath");
        Random r = new Random();
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            int num = r.nextInt(10);
            out.write(num + "\n");
        }

        out.close();
    }
```

Am I on the right track? Also how would I go about running this program via cmd. I know the commands for compiling and running it  but I think I need a tester to run this. So could somebody give me instructions on how I could go about running this code via cmd.

Edit: Got it working! Thanks everyone for the help!

Comment: Some reading would be prudent: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/index.html?utm_source=twitterfeed&utm_medium=twitter , http://csis.pace.edu/~bergin/KarelJava2ed/ch2/javamain.html , http://java67.blogspot.com/2012/08/what-is-main-method-in-java-why-main-is.html

Comment: (One question at a time.. and make sure it's reflected in the title.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're close with your printing.
Instead of doing

```
out.write(num + "\n");
```

youll instead want to do

```
out.println(num);
```

which is cross platform (and in my opinion, easier to read).

Additionally, in order to run your program from command line, all you'll need to do is add a main method in your class, like so

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException  {
    int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    String filePath = args[1];
    YourClass c = new YourClass();
    c.generate(n, filePath);

}
```

this main assumes you're passing in 2 parameters from command line, the number followed by the filename

Hope this was helpful

Answer (score 1):

`filePath` is a variable that holds the path of the file, so you don't want to enclose it in double quotes. If you do, it is treated as a `String`, so the program searches for a file with path `filePath`.

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(filePath); // no ""
```

The "tester" can run the program the same way you run it: `java programName`

Answer (score 1):

```
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("filePath");
```

Should be

```
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(filePath);
```

You want to use the variable name in the parameters, what you were passing instead is a string.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to test this:

1. Introduce a main method in your class and call your generate method from main.
2. Add a unit test framework jars and write a unit test class & methods for this.